# AWS access key is showing up in browser url when accessing the s3 content from heroku

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, django-settings

I have deployed my django app to heroku and using Amazon s3 bucket to store the static files and I see there is no issues in getting data from s3 buckets to heroku. But, when I'm testing to see the content storage location i'm getting the url path in addition with the AccesskeyID

https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/img/front_cover.JPG?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAXPKPZLYKLRB7DR4N&Signature=JzTU0DpmbGSBRpYHwV8Dvt0p1QQ%3D&Expires=1590936351

So I'm concerned showing up access id in the browser URl, do we have an option to disable this in heroku or django settings or in AWS

Comment: What is your code behind the URL generation? The library you use should support both public (no signature) and presigned URLs (like the one you posted). To use the former you'll need to make sure the objects are public and that you indeed are OK for them to be such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html) and the AWSAccessKeyId is actually part of its structure.

Both this and Signature need to match for this to be displayed to the end user.

If security is a concern just generate IAM user which is minimum permissions. Remember the secret key should be kept secret though, this is the equivalent of a password. An access key however, is actually retrievable through anyone in your AWS account, closer to a username.

Comment: After going through many web pages was able to figure out that, making s3 bucket public is disabling the AccessKey in url which makes sense. Though mine is an web app still I just want to keep the files in bucket as private allowing to users who are logged into my app.